# Header X-Robots-Tag being set twice in Express.js

Tags: javascript, express, header, http-headers

I am trying to add X-Robots-Tag: all as a header to all requests on my express app. I have this middle ware code;

```js
this.app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('x-robots-tag', 'all')
    next();
});
```

I have also tried removing the `x-robots-tag: none` header then adding `x-robots-tag: all` it does not change the result.

[image: Image of HTML response headers]